# How to avoid deeply if then statements to avoid warnings in pmd?

Tags: java

Is the way so that i can reduce the deeply if then statements for the below code

```
if (presenterManager != null) {
        IFieldPresenter modeFieldPresenter = presenterManager.getFieldPresenter(ATTR_MODE);
        if (modeFieldPresenter != null) {
            String modeLV =  ((ListBoxValue)modeFieldPresenter.getState().getSingleValue()).getValue();
           String customerAccountPK = getContext().getRequestParam("parentPK");
           String customerAccountId = toObjectId(customerAccountPK);
            LOG.debug(" modeLV = "+modeLV);
            LOG.debug( "customerAccountId = "+customerAccountId);

            if(!LV_AUTOMATIC.equals(modeLV)) {
                Window.open(CONFIGURE_URL_PREFIX + customerAccountId, "_blank", "");
                return getInitialEvent();

            }
        }
    }
```

I want to avoid the deeply if for  if(!LV_AUTOMATIC.equals(modeLV)) this if statement.

Comment: if ( presenterManager == null ){ return; }
or break, jump out of a loop, ...
This is not deeply nested, and no, you can't always avoid code like this

Comment: You can extract the block it is in, into a method.  Your IDE should be able to help you do that.

Comment: You can also invert your `if` conditions, extracting this entire block into a method would help with that.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: you can extract the code, yes, but you would still have the if structures

Comment: @Stultuske correct, but not nested if structures.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: yes you would. just because you change where you've written the code, doesn't change the flow of the application. It might make programs like sonar think that they're not nested anymore, because they're a bit easier to read, but logically, they stay nested.

Comment: You can also modify your code in a way that `presenterManager` and/or `modeFieldPresenter` can never be `null`, thereby avoiding two `if` statements completely.

Comment: Since the checking of condition is done based on the previous value within the if statement I cant check for presenterManager and/or modeFieldPresenter can never be null

Comment: Can some show me code snippet to resolve the above issue in java 7

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can do this.

```
Optional<InitalEvent> event = Optional.ofNullable(presenterManager)
    .map(p -> p.getFieldPresenter(ATTR_MODE))
    .map(p -> (ListBoxValue)p.getState().getSingleValue()).getValue()) 
    .filter(!LV_AUTOMATIC.equals(modeLV))
    .map(modeLV -> {
       String customerAccountId = toObjectId(getContext().getRequestParam("parentPK"));
        LOG.debug(" modeLV = "+modeLV+", customerAccountId = "+customerAccountId);

        Window.open(CONFIGURE_URL_PREFIX + customerAccountId, "_blank", "");
        return getInitialEvent();
    });
}
```